# how to handle exceptions from C# class file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

Delete method implemented in DataManipulation class (DataManipulation.cs file), SqlException will catch when there any exception comes from DB, and there i want to customize the exception error message for the user and then i want to pass/display that error message from class file to respective .aspx page.

I can do that with scriptmanager.registerstartupscript, but i believe it is not standard, So i want to display that the custom error message in user control.

please provide your suggestions, Thanks

```
    public class DataManipulation
   {
    public DataManipulation()
    { }
       public void Delete(ClientInfo info)
        {

            try
            {
               ......
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

                    string msg = "Delete Error: ...................";
                    msg += ex.Message.Replace("\'", "").Replace("\"", "");



             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Means you wants to display exception from `SqlException ` to User ??

Comment: Right, I want to display exception from SqlException to user.

Comment: Why can you pass the information in the error like any other kind of information?